# Rails Models Validation 1 Word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validates-uniqueness-of

I try to add a validation from a blog category only limited at 1 word.

But I try this `length: { maximum: 1 }`

I doesn't work. Is there a validation to validaes only one word and not uniqueness?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a custom validation:

```
validates :category, uniqueness: true
validate :category_in_1_word

private

def category_in_1_word
  if category.to_s.squish.split.size != 1
    errors.add(:category, 'must be 1 word')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

you can try:

```
validates :category, :format => { :with => /^[A-Za-z]+$/, :message => "Must be single word" }
```

Comment: Most clever solution! I would only use this regex `^\S*$`

Answer (score 0):

No Rails doesn't have the validation you need, but you can easily create a custom one:

Try something like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate do
    if ... # any custom logic goes here
      errors.add :title, "is wrong"
    end
  end
end
```